# __set() method echoing property value twice

Tags: php, get, set, magic-methods

I am new to php world.I am trying to understand how **__set()** magic method works in php.Here i create a new property using ***__set()*** method.I have a if statement which checks for whether the property is already exists or not.If not exists ,then it creates the property and assign it a value.Here i am checking for two properties.They are ***$newProp*** and ***$anotherProp .***  ***$newProp*** doesn't exists.So it creates the property and echoing it's value twice.But for ***$anotherProp***,which already exists,The ***else condition*** didn't trigger.Here i am facing two problem

1.It's echoing the property value twice.

2.Else condition is not working    at all.I mean if property already
   exists it doesn't print any    message.

```
      class myclass {

        public $anotherProp='Another property value';

        public function __set($prop,$val){
           if(! property_exists($this,$prop) ){

              $this->prop=$val;
              echo $this->prop;

           }else{
              echo 'property already exists';
           }
        }
}

$obj=new myclass();

$obj->newProp='i am a new property';

$obj->anotherProp='i am another property';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `__set()` you are accidentally creating yet *another* `public` property called `$this->prop` implicitly because you don't use the variable `$prop` to determine which property gets its value set. The subsequent `echo` happened twice because that as-yet-uncreated property called `__set()`.

Use `$this->$prop` to solve that part of it, and have a look at the [PHP documentation on "variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), where you'll find examples for variable object properties.

```
public function __set($prop, $val) {
  if (!property_exists($this, $prop)) {
    // Set the property dynamically
    $this->$prop = $val;
    echo $this->$prop;
  }
  else {
    echo 'property already exists';
  }
}
```

Now the reason you don't see `property already exists` when calling it on `$anotherProp` is because [`__set()` is called for inaccessible properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).  It is *not* called for properties declared `public`. If you instead declare

```
private $anotherProp = 'i am another property';
```

you will see the `__set()` method called and the *already exists* message printed.

[Here's the whole thing in action](http://3v4l.org/uKQiH)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a typo there

```
$this->prop = $val;
```

should be

```
$this->$prop = $val;
```

`$this->prop` means 'the property of this whose name is "prop"' (=direct reference). `$this->$prop` means 'the property of this whose name is stored in $prop` (=indirect reference).

Second, `__set` is only invoked on undefined properties, so this

```
$obj->someExistingProp = ...
```

doesn't call `__set`. This makes your `property_exists` check essentially useless (because it always be `false` in `__set`).